# The very same sound issue on Ubuntu 20.04. HELP!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am new to linux. I got an Asus TP500L laptop and running on Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works fine but the sound. The output device I manage to switched it from dummy output and now it is appearing HDMI/DisplayPort-Build-in-Audio on the sound setting. There's no other build-in options but the HDMI. I must say I have found it very tiring to find the ways into resolving this matter. I have tried on askubuntu, foss, linuxquestions etc...forums on resting the pulseaudio,alsa,down-grading kernels, etc... even watch youtube videos but still no luck in getting the sound going. It has taken a lot of time working it out. Please advise what I did wrong. I do not believe it is a hardware issue.

I hope the information below given will give you a brief idea of my system. Let me know if you need more info from me. Really appreciate your assistance.

`$ lspci -nnk | grep -i -A7 audio`

```
00:03.0 <font color="#CC0000"><b>Audio</b></font> device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD <font color="#CC0000"><b>Audio</b></font> Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD <font color="#CC0000"><b>Audio</b></font> Controller [8086:2010]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series USB xHCI HC [1043:16ad]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series HECI [1043:16ad]
```

`$ aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`~$ lshw | grep -A11 multimedia`

```
*-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:f7a10000-f7a13fff
```

Alsamixer
[Alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv9LQ.png)

Sound settings
[Sound Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHyF5.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue on a Asus Zenbook with the same audio device a while back:

1. Open terminal and type `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Add this at the end of the file: `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`
3. Restart the system.

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: It is already on options snd-hda-intel model=auto and it still doesn't work. =(